# Is there a way to calculate I/O and memory of current process in C?

Tags: c, linux

If I use

```
/usr/bin/time -f"%e,%P,%M,%I,%O"
```

I get (for the last three placeholders) the memory the process used, and if there was some input and output during it.

Obviously, it's easy to get `%e` or something like it using `sys/time.h`, but is there a way to get `%M`, `%I` and `%O` programmatically?

Comment: You could `fork`, `execv` and `pipe`. Although @esorton's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23209370/184741) is the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read and parse the files in the `/proc` filesystem.  `/proc/self` refers to the process accessing the `/proc` filesystem.

`/proc/self/statm` contains information about memory usage, measured in pages.  Sample output:

```
% cat /proc/self/statm
1115 82 63 12 0 79 0
```

Fields are `size resident share text lib data dt`; see the `proc` manual page for some additional details.

`/proc/self/io` contains the I/O for the current process.  Sample output:

```
% cat /proc/self/io
rchar: 2012
wchar: 0
syscr: 6
syscw: 0
read_bytes: 0
write_bytes: 0
cancelled_write_bytes: 0
```

Unfortunately, `io` isn't documented in the `proc` manual page (at least on my Debian system).  I had too check the `iotop` source code to see how it obtained the per process I/O information.

Comment: Thanks. That works. Doing a bit more research I found getrusage, http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html. That's exactly what `usr/bin/time` is reporting, with `RUSAGE_SELF`, afaik.

Comment: @DervinThunk good find; I wasn't aware of that command.  It does appear to be a better solution for what you want to do.

Comment: It's best to refer to upstream manual pages ([Linux man-pages project](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/index.html)) for kernel and core C library stuff. `/proc/[PID]/io` is documented there on the [man 5 proc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) page. Distributions use it, too, but changes take some time to propagate.